# How to compute the volume of a region transformed by a matrix?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, multivariable-calculus

This is a rewrite of the OP's question to emphasize what I think are the research level issues here.

Let $\mathscr{R}$ be a bounded convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $H : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^r$ be a surjective linear map for $r<n$. How can we compute the volume of $H(\mathscr{R})$? Of course, the answer to this question will depend on how $\mathscr{R}$ is given. I don't know what the OP intended, but here are some options I can see:

- $\mathscr{R}$ is a convex polytope, given as a list of vertices.
- $\mathscr{R}$ is a convex polytope, given as a list of facet inequalities
- $\mathscr{R}$ is a $\{ f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \leq c \}$, for $f$ some convex polynomial. We could generalize this to $\{ f_1 \leq c_1,\ f_2 \leq c_2,\ \cdots,\ f_N \leq c_N \}$ for some list of convex polynomials $f_j$.
- There is some polynomial function $\phi$ sending $\mathbb{R}^n$ to symmetric $k \times k$ matrices, and $\mathcal{R}$ is the set of $\vec{x}$ so that $\phi(\vec{x})$ has at least $\ell$ nonnegative eigenvalues. (This sort of formulation is very common in [semidefinite programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming).)

There will probably also be different answers depending on whether we are considering $r$ and $n$ bounded, $r$ bounded with $n \to \infty$, or both $r$ and $n$ going to $\infty$.

The original question is below.

---

Consider a convex body $\mathscr{R}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$  and a rank-$r$ matrix $\mathbf{H}=[\mathbf{h}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{h}_n]\in \mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$. Assume that the $r$-dimensional volume of $\mathbf{H}\mathscr{R}=\{\mathbf{Hr}:\mathbf{r}\in\mathscr{R}\}$ is finite and nonzero.

> **How to compute it?**

This problem is extended by the previous one ([The $r$-dimensional volume of the Minkowski sum of $n$ ($n\geq r$) line sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349554/the-r-dimensional-volume-of-the-minkowski-sum-of-n-n-geq-r-line-sets)).

Comment: this looks like a rather standard multivariate calculus question.

Comment: What is "the previous one"?  (Oh, I guess https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349554/the-r-dimensional-volume-of-the-minkowski-sum-of-n-n-geq-r-line-sets .)

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Since $r < n$, I don't think this is a standard problem. But it needs more information to be answerable. How are we given the convex body $\mathcal{R}$? If it is a polytope given as the convex hull of its vertices, then $H \mathcal{R}$ is the convex hull of the images of those vertices; see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9573 for software in this case.

Comment: If $\mathcal{R}$ is a polytope given by facet inequalities, POLYMAKE https://polymake.org/doku.php can compute its vertices but possibly at the cost of an exponential explosion. I suspect there are smarter things to do in this case.

Comment: If $\mathcal{R}$ is not a polytope but, for example, $\{ f \leq 0 \}$ for a convex polynomial $f$, then I don't know what to do.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of rewriting the question; see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4417/ .

Comment: Thanks for DES-SupportsMonicaAndTransfolk's help. The edited question is more precise and tractable. Actually, this is a problem I met in the communication theory. I am not sure the region is indeed a convex polytope.  Another interesting question is how to decompose the region into a disjoint union of subregions. 
In the original problem, I mentioned the rank of the matrix $\mathbf{H}$, which implies that $r\le n$. It is meaningful to emphasize $n>r$.

Comment: http://marc.mezzarobba.net/papers/LairezMezzarobbaSafey_Volumes_v1_2019.pdf explains a general approach, for not necessarily convex semi-algebraic sets.

By Tarski-Seidenberg theorem, a projection of a semialgebraic set remains semialgebraic, so one does not need to worry about $r<n$ too much. One can e.g. always compute an appropriate (semialgebraic) triangulation.